# Multinomial Expansion of Finite Series to a Power.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, multinomial-coefficients

I am having some trouble understanding the multinomial theorem, and I wonder if someone could confirm if my solution is correct. Ultimately, I want to write out the solution in an expanded form in order to improve my understanding.

Using multinomial theorem we can rewrite $\left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}z^{i}a_{i}\right]^{q}$ as,

> $$\left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}z^{i}a_{i}\right]^{q} =\sum_{i_{1}+i_{2}+\cdots+i_{m-1}=q}\dbinom{q}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{m-1}}\prod_{t=1}^{m-1}z^{i_{t}}a_{i_{t}},$$

where $\dbinom{q}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{m-1}}=\dbinom{q}{i_{1}!i_{2}!\cdots i_{m-1}!},$

> $$=\sum_{i_{1}=0}^{m-1}\sum_{i_{2}=0}^{m-1}\cdots\sum_{i_{q}=0}^{m-1}\dbinom{q}{i_{1}!i_{2}!\cdots i_{m-1}!}\prod_{t=1}^{m-1}z^{i_{t}}a_{i_{t}}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Some issues. One, you're indexing your summands from $0$ to $m-1$, so the lower limit of your products should be $0$ not $1$. Two, you substituted into the multinomial theorem incorrectly. Three, the formula for the multinomial coefficient is

$$\binom{q}{i_0,\cdots,i_{m-1}}=\frac{q!}{i_0!\cdots i_{m-1}!}\color{Red}{\ne \binom{q}{i_0!\cdots i_{m-1}!}}. $$

The binomial coefficient you've written (I made it red above) is incorrect. Notice $i_0!\cdots i_{m-1}!$ is almost surely bigger than $q$ anyway, so that binomial coefficient is usually $0$.

Fourth, in your second display formula you've written $\sum_{i_1}\cdots\sum_{i_{m-1}}$ but you can't just drop the condition that the sum the $i$ terms must be $q$.

The multinomial theorem says

$$ \left(\sum_{t=0}^{m-1} c_t\right)^q=\sum_{i_0+\cdots+i_{m-1}=q}\binom{q}{i_0,\cdots,i_{m-1}}\prod_{t=0}^{m-1}c_t^{i_{\large t}} $$

If we substitute $c_t=a_tz^t$ then this becomes

$$ \sum_{i_0+\cdots+i_{m-1}=q}\binom{q}{i_0,\cdots,i_{m-1}}\prod_{t=0}^{m-1} \left(a_tz^t\right)^{i_{\large t}}.$$

Comment: First off, thank you for the quick response. With regards to your fourth comment, how do I include the condition? Is it simply $\sum_{i_{2}=0}^{i_{1}}\sum_{i_{3}=0}^{i_{2}}\cdots\sum_{i_{m}=0}^{i_{m-1}}\left(\frac{q!}{i_{0}!\cdots i_{m-1}!}\right)\prod_{t=0}^{m-1}\left(z^{t}a_{t}\right)^{i_{t}}\mid_{i_{1}+i_{2}+\cdots+i_{m-1}=q}$?

Comment: Include it however you want to. It's already included when we write $i_0+\cdots+i_{m-1}=q$ under a single summation. Although the way you've written it seems to force $i_0\ge i_1\ge i_2\ge\cdots$ (you forgot to write $i_0$ again) which is *not* a condition on the $i$s.

Comment: I am a bit of a loss, I am finding it hard to understand the following example: Using multinomial expansion we can rewrite $\left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{i!}\left(\frac{m}{\overline{\gamma}}z\right)^{i}\right]^{n_{1}}$
  as,$$\left[\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{i!}\left(\frac{m}{\overline{\gamma}}z\right)^{i}\right]^{n_{1}} =\sum_{n_{2}=0}^{n_{1}}\sum_{n_{3}=0}^{n_{2}}\cdots\sum_{n_{m}=0}^{n_{m}-1}\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}\left(\frac{1}{i!}\right)^{n_{i+1}-n_{i+2}}\binom{n_{i+1}}{n_{i+2}}\left(\frac{m}{\overline{\gamma}}z\right)^{\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}j\left(n_{j+1}-n_{j+2}\right)},$$
 where $n_{m+1}=0.$